# Using ASP.NET MVC ValidateFor HTML helper together with unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

1. Is it possible to use Html.ValidateFor together with unobtrusive validation? I want to be able to do following:

   < !-- I want to specify validation using data-val* attributes -->
   < input type="text" data-val-required/>

   < !-- I want to use HTML helper to inject data-val* attributes using view model attributes  -->
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)

   < !-- I want also be able to render input control myself, but also include validation from viewmodel attributes, and eat it too -->

   @{ Html.ValidateFor(m => m.Age); }
2. Why ValidateFor disabled when unobtrusive validation is enabled? What is an easy way to use both?

Answer (score 2):

I added an HTML extension method that will inspect model metadata and yield all `data-val*` attributes (for consumption by `jquery.unobtrusive.validation`).

This way I have full control over how control is rendered (sometimes Html.*For family of methods would produce name and id attributes that don't suit my needs, also adding extra arguments might get clunky).

Note, you still need to have `input` control inside form element (required by `jquery.unobtrusive.validation`).

```
public static MvcHtmlString Validation<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) {
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    IDictionary<string, object> dataValAttrs = html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), metadata);

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var dataValAttr in dataValAttrs) {
        stringBuilder.Append(' ').Append(dataValAttr.Key).Append("=\"").Append(dataValAttr.Value).Append('"');
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

And here is how this method is to be used:

```
<textarea name="Description" class="input-block-level" @Html.Validation(m => m.FormData.Description)></textarea>
@Html.ValidationMessage("Description")
```

Notice that you can't use `Html.ValidationMessageFor` version here, since it will create name `FormData_Description` which is different from `Description` I want in this case (for the purpose of POST action binding to a FormData object.